# Postgresql error: could not open segment 1 of relation base/20983/2416

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm running a Postgresql query and getting the following error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  could not open segment 1 of relation base/20983/24161 (target block 5046584): No such file or directory

The query is of the format 'SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE ("locations"."id" IN (115990, 78330, 77891, 78248, ...)' with about 600 ids in the IN clause - not an optimal query I know but it's what I have to work with for the moment!

The server is running PostgreSQL 8.4.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1, 64-bit. Postgis 1.5 is also installed, and the locations table contains a geometry column.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates serious database corruption, one of the database's files containing the table data (of something in the system catalogue?) is missing. I doubt you'll be able to do much beyond restoring the data from a backup.

Comment: Thanks, not what I was hoping to hear but at least I know the answer now! Is there any way to get more info about the error? The weird thing is if I do a full select on the entire table I get all the records returned, but the query throws the error. I'm therefore guessing it has something to do with an index/primary key being corrupted, so hoping if I can just rebuild it...

Comment: if you do `select oid::regclass from pg_class where relfilenode = 24161` that should tell you which relation (table or index) is problematic. you can start postgresql with the "-P" option to force it to avoid using indices to access system tables while you try and rebuild things. but imho you should be aiming to get things to the point where you can dump the data out and rebuild the database, since this could just be the first of many problems with your current one.